# Solving $(1 + i) z - 2 \overline{z} = -11 + 25i$

Tags: complex-numbers

How do we find the complex number $z$ that satisfies

$$(1 + i) z - 2 \overline{z} = -11 + 25i.$$

How should I start? Am I supposed to express $z$ as $x+yi$?

Comment: Yes - the next hint is to equate real and imaginary parts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since both, left hand side and right hand side of
\begin{align*}
(1 + i) z - 2 \overline{z} = -11 + 25i\tag{1}
\end{align*}
represent a complex number, we can equate real and  imaginary part  of them.  We  set $z=x+iy$ with real part $x$ and imaginary part $y$.

> We obtain
>   \begin{align*}
> \Re\left((1+i)(x+iy)-2(x-iy)\right)&=(x-y)-2x\\
> &=-x-y\tag{2}\\
> \Im\left((1+i)(x+iy)-2(x-iy)\right)&=(x+y)+2y\\
> &=x+3y\tag{3}
> \end{align*}
>
> Equating real part (2) and imaginary part (3) with the RHS of (1) we get
>   \begin{align*}
> -x-y&=-11\\
> x+3y&=25
> \end{align*}
>   and finally obtain 
>   \begin{align*}
> z&=x+iy\color{blue}{=4+7i}
> \end{align*}

Answer (score 4):

Hint:   take the conjugate of the equation, then solve the system in $\,z,\bar z\,$ for $\,z\,$:

$$
\begin{cases}
\begin{align}
(1 + i) z - 2 \overline{z} = -11 + 25i \\
 - 2 z + (1 - i) \overline{z} = -11 - 25i
\end{align}
\end{cases}
$$

Comment: sorry how do I solve the left side? the right would be -22 I'm assuming

Comment: @mariabendy Like you'd solve any system of two equations with two unknowns. For example, eliminate $\,\bar z\,$ between the two and you get an equation in $\,z\,$ alone. To do that, you could multiply the first equation by $\,(1-i)\,$, the second equation by $\,2\,$, then add them together and you'll see the terms in $\,\bar z\,$ cancel out..

Comment: So, on the left side, my two equations now are (1-i) 2z(overline on z) and -2z(overline on z). I'm stuck...

Comment: @mariabendy Which *two* equations? After you follow the steps from my previous comment and add the two equations, you end up with one single equation in $\,z\,$ alone: $$
(1-i)\cdot(1+i)z - 2 \cdot 2z = (1-i)(-11+25i)+2(-11-25i) 
$$ This is a simple linear equation in $\,z\,$ which is straightforward to solve.